# Is this Ellayn race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, races

The Ellayn are a falcon-winged fey creatures that dwell in the skies of Faerie, the ellayn are relatives of the elves and their long-standing allies. They live in tight-knit family units consisting of around 6 ellayn. These fey beings nest in massive, ancient trees or atop rocky mountain tops.

They are humanoid in appearance, with slightly pointed ears and horns of varying sizes. Ellayn wings are small, unable to properly carry them through the air and resemble those of falcons or other smaller raptor birds.

- **Ability Score Increase:** Your Wisdom score increases by 2 and your Dexterity score increases by 1.
- **Size:** Most Ellayn stand at about 5'3 to 5'4, with the tallest being close to 6 feet in height.
- **Age.** Ellayn are considered adults when they reach the age of 14, whereupon they are forced to leave their nests and travel the world. Being creatures of Faerie, they are long lived, able to live to the age of 400.
- **Speed:** Your base walking speed is 30 ft.
- **Children of the Air.** Your long jump is up to 20 feet and your high jump is up to 10 feet, with or without a running start. Additionally, when you fall at least 10 feet above the ground, you can use your reaction to extend your wings and glide horizontally a number of feet equal to your walking speed. You determine the direction of the glide and using this reaction negates any fall damage you would otherwise receive.
- **Ellayn Magic.** You know the Gust cantrip and cast it without requiring any components. Wisdom is your spellcasting ability for this spell.
- **Fey Ancestry.** You have advantage on saving throws you make to avoid or end the charmed condition on yourself.
- **Languages.** You can speak, read and write Common, Sylvan and Auran.

Comment: I have a few things I'm noticing: #1: Why *3* languages? All other races can only speak two(without background or class traits). #2: If the ellayan have wings, and they "can't fly", how can they glide? #3: How many "Fey Ancestry" traits(elves have Fey Ancestry trait, and they have very different qualities) are there? Isn't there only one?

Answer (score 3):

## It's ready for playtest

Let's compare the Ellayn trait by trait to the most similar race in official material: the hadozee.

### Dexterous Feet vs Children of the Air part 1

> **Dexterous Feet.** As a bonus action, you can use your feet to manipulate an object, open or close a door or container, or pick up or set down a Tiny object.

Both minor traits of better jumping and manipulating items with your feet are approximately equal in my mind. They will occasionally come up but don't contribute substantially to the power level of the race.

### Children of the Air part 2 vs Glide

> **Glide**. When you fall at least 10 feet above the ground, you can use your reaction to extend your skin membranes to glide horizontally a number of feet equal to your walking speed, and you take 0 damage from the fall. You determine the direction of the glide.

These are fundamentally the same feature although the wording differs. Clearly equals.

### Ellayn Magic + Fey Ancestry vs Hadozee Resilience

> **Hadozee Resilience.** The magic that runs in your veins heightens your natural defenses. When you take damage, you can use your reaction to roll a d6. Add your proficiency bonus to the number rolled, and reduce the damage you take by an amount equal to that total (minimum of 0 damage). You can use this trait a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus. You regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

Having played a hadozee once, and having played many goliath (who have a similar feature), I can't undersell the power of Hadozee Resilience. Overall, this is somewhat comparable to a self-targeted *healing word* spell on a reaction PB times per day.

The number of times I've been saved from going down in a fight thanks to Stone's Endurance is absurd. However, Hadozee Resilience is somewhat worse than Stone's Endurance meaning more attacks will be strong enough to bring you to 0 hit points even with the reaction. As such, I'll hedge a little bit when comparing this feature.

The Ellayn, now, get two features in exchange for it, both of which are situationally useful. *Gust* can be quite strong in its niche, and Fey Ancestry never hurts.

That said, I'd still give the edge to the Hadozee here as most characters don't have a consistent use for their reaction and Hadozee Resilience is a great one.

### Conclusion

Overall, the Hadozee has a slight advantage when compared to the Ellayn. This places the race squarely within the range of officially released races.

I might shore up the wording of Children of the Air to line up with the officially released Hadozee, but apart from that, the race looks ready for playtest to me.

Comment: Would the increased jumping height not synergize really well with the gliding ability?

Comment: @MarioAleksandarMarinov You are still limited in movement to your walking speed. I don't see any way to abuse the extra jump, and from when I've played a hadozee it is rarely much different than any other flying race which multiples have been released thus far.

Comment: @MarioAleksandarMarinov the only benefit of high jump-falling-gliding is that you ignore the terrain in squares over which you glide, but that is at best situationally beneficial as you need ceiling height *and* dangerous or slowing terrain to cross.